# What is the correct usage "Last time/The last time"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you please clarify the meaning of the following sentences and the correct way to use them.

We have been to a shop many times in the past and the last time I went with my brother.

Would "*Last time we went to the shop we bought eggs*" and "*The last time we went to the shops we bought eggs*" be the same or do they have different meanings?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Last time/The last time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510112/last-time-the-last-time) as asked here previously

Comment: @FF If you upvote the answer at the duplicate, one can CV here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last time/The last time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510112/last-time-the-last-time)

Comment: DV and voted to close as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same (and the sentence should have a comma):

"[The] Last time we went to the shop" is an adverbial clause:

"[The] Last time we went to the shop, we bought eggs = We bought eggs **on the last occasion that we went to the shop**."

In essence, it does not differ from

"**Yesterday,** we bought eggs" or "We bought eggs **yesterday**."

Comment: Basically they are the same but the "The" is optional? Is there any reason why you would use one over the other? Would you use one over the other if you had only been to the shops to buy eggs (Not a series of events)?